# how to fix this Task/CancellationToken issue?

Tags: c#, task, cancellationtokensource

I'm running this code;

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = DoSomething();
            Task.WaitAny(task);

            Console.WriteLine(task.Result);

            Console.Write("Press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void WriteLine(string str, params string[] param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str, param);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str, param);
        }

        async static Task<string> DoSomething()
        {
            int timeout = 20;
            int count = 1;
            CancellationTokenSource cts;
            string output;                
            do
            {
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
                //does also happen with
                //output = await Task<string>.Run(() => test(count, timeout, cts.Token));
                output = await Task<string>.Run(() => test(count, timeout, cts.Token), cts.Token);

                if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    WriteLine(string.Format("Retry. Count value {2}, Test Sleep time {0}, Method timeout {1}", output, timeout, count));
                    timeout += 50;
                    count++;
                }
            } while (cts.IsCancellationRequested);

            return string.Format("Count value {2}, Test Sleep time {0}, Method timeout {1}", output, timeout, count);
        }

        async static Task<string> test(int count, int timeout, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            int sleep = 400 - (count * 5);
            await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(sleep), ct);

            if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                WriteLine(string.Format("Succeed. Count value {2}, Test Sleep time {0}, Method timeout {1}", sleep, timeout, count)); 
            }
            return sleep.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm getting this output

```
Retry. Count value 1, Test Sleep time 395, Method timeout 20
Retry. Count value 2, Test Sleep time 390, Method timeout 70
Retry. Count value 3, Test Sleep time 385, Method timeout 120
Retry. Count value 4, Test Sleep time 380, Method timeout 170
Retry. Count value 5, Test Sleep time 375, Method timeout 220
Retry. Count value 6, Test Sleep time 370, Method timeout 270
Retry. Count value 7, Test Sleep time 365, Method timeout 320
Succeed. Count value 8, Test Sleep time 360, Method timeout 370
Retry. Count value 8, Test Sleep time 360, Method timeout 370
Succeed. Count value 9, Test Sleep time 355, Method timeout 420
```

How to fix the issue at `Count value 8` ?

It should say Succeed and stop there.

Comment: FYI, I use timeout = 50 and fail to reproduce the issue on Xamarin.

Comment: You check `CancellationToken` inside `test` method, then it go to the canceled state, then you check `CancellationToken` inside `DoSomething` method.

Comment: One question, why don't you just use `output = await test(count, timeout, cts.Token);`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a race condition, because `IsCancellationRequested` can be changed from `false` to `true` during your "Succeed" and "Retry" check. It is hard to suggest a proper fix without knowing actual context of this code.